# cron job 'django-cron' not running in ubuntu cron tab

Tags: django, ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-10.04, django-cron

I am using django_cron for a schedule a job, when i am use  python manage.py runcrons this work good. but after adding the cron job in ubuntu cron list job is not executing.
My setting.py is:

```
CRON_CLASSES = [
    "home.cron.HomeCronJob",
]

FAILED_RUNS_CRONJOB_EMAIL_PREFIX = []
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    '..................'
    'django_cron',
)
```

My cron.py file is:

```
from django_cron import CronJobBase, Schedule
from home.management.commands.auto_renueva import republishAds
class HomeCronJob(CronJobBase):
    RUN_EVERY_MINS = 2
    MIN_NUM_FAILURES = 2
    schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=RUN_EVERY_MINS)
    code = 'home.home_cron_job'

    def do(self):
        republishAds()
```

then I have created a shell script for run this job, cron.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash
source /home/cis/ENV/muna/bin/activate
python /home/cis/DjangoLive/Newmunda/mund2anuncios/manage.py runcrons
deactivate
```

and the code i have added in ubuntu cron file are:

```
*/1 * * * *  /home/cis/DjangoLive/Newmunda/mund2anuncios/crons.sh >> /home/cis/Desktop/crons.log 3 >> /home/cis/Desktop/cron_errors.log
```

Please suggest me what i am doing wrong Here.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

As a guess

```
python /home/cis/DjangoLive/Newmunda/mund2anuncios/manage.py runcrons
```

Will fail because PATH is not set in cron environment. You should include the full path to the python interpreter.

Other common error in cron jobs are no execution permissions on scripts. Normally cron errors are emailed to root, so you should have more info about errors on root mailbox

Comment: Hii Raul, I have given 0755 permission to cron.sh file and also code is working when i am going to run ./cron.sh

Comment: And did you try using full path for python?

Comment: no, bcs shell script activating virtualenv, but let me try full path.

Comment: Then, you will no need full path on cron.sh, but you should check that activate doesn't rely on PATH or any other environment variable to run

Comment: not working with full path as well. i am not figure out what i am doing wrong here.